# Visually managing MongoDB documents and collections

Tags: windows, user-interface, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB in a reporting system and have to delete a whole bunch of test documents.  While I don't have too much trouble using the JSON-based command-line tools, it gets extremely tedious to have to keep searching for documents, copy-and-pasting OIDs, etc., *especially* from a command prompt window (ever tried to "mark" text that wraps multiple lines?)

How can I visually inspect the databases and collections, perform some simple CRUD tasks and manage multiple scripts in a proper window (not a command prompt)?

Comment: I'm voting to close my own question; at the time it was written, the landscape was barren and even one or two answers was a miracle. But now there seem to be plenty of tools and the answers are just going to turn into a poll over time.

Comment: I'll be happy to maintain the [top answer as community wiki and update as MongoDB admin tools evolve](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6691013/1269037).

Comment: My one and only issue with SO is how aggressive we are in closing questions. Take this one - I found it via a Google search, it's highly upvoted, and has an excellent and well-maintained accepted answer that was extremely helpful to me, a developer. Why close it then? This question has not proven to solicit debates, argument, polling or extended discussion. If it is closed, we reduce the body of knowledge that programmers have access to, which is the opposite of the spirit and intent of SO, IMHO.

Comment: @RyanShripat: I don't know why my name doesn't appear in the list, but you do realize that this is *my* question and **I** voted to close it? There are a lot of obsolete and/or unhelpful answers here, some duplicate answers, and some actual spam that you can't see right now because it was deleted. I got value out of this question at the time, but it's just not necessary anymore, and eliminating this kind of noise was *precisely* the spirit and intent of Stack Overflow. I'd probably say it shouldn't be *deleted*, but it should definitely stay closed.

Comment: Hi @Aaronaught - I saw your comment saying that you're voting to close it, but ignored it because I think that's actually irrelevant. 'Your' question now belongs to the Community. There ARE obsolete and unhelpful answers here, but the top-voted one, with 70 votes, is extremely up-to-date and helpful. I made this Google search yesterday, and found this, so I'd say it's very much necessary - I got value out of this just yesterday.

Comment: wrt deleted vs closed - I never considered the difference here - I guess it depends, for me, on if a user with low rep can see the closed question and benefit from it and whether users can edit the top-voted (or any) answer and whether users can add more up-to-date answers.

Comment: Here you are: https://github.com/rsercano/mongoclient written in meteorJS, has most platforms distributions.

Comment: Another "closed", highly upvoted StackOverflow question for programmers with mental stack overflow trying to discern what tools to use, as programmers, at the best source for programmers with mental stack overlow trying to discern what tools to use.  But, of course, the question must be closed!!!!! ... because, well, some questions about choice of tools & libraries can become overly opinion-based.  Need to protect the community from unhelpful questions first & foremost, first & foremost!

Comment: @Aaronaught: if some answers are obsolete, then the problem is with those answers, not with the entire question. The concept of [keyhole solutions](https://causeprioritization.org/Keyhole_solution) applies here.

Comment: I think a question like this could find a good home on [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) but as always, make sure to read their [help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting. Actually here's a [cross site duplicate](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1041/mongodb-database-administration-gui) (with seemingly worse answers)

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Here are some popular MongoDB GUI administration tools:

### Open source

- [dbKoda](https://www.dbkoda.com/) - cross-platform, tabbed editor with auto-complete, syntax highlighting and code formatting (plus auto-save, something Studio 3T doesn't support), visual tools (explain plan, real-time performance dashboard, query and aggregation pipeline builder), profiling manager, storage analyzer, index advisor, convert MongoDB commands to Node.js syntax etc. Lacks in-place document editing and the ability to switch themes.

  [image: dbKoda screenshot]
- [Nosqlclient](https://www.nosqlclient.com/) - multiple shell output tabs, autocomplete, schema analyzer, index management, user/role management, live monitoring, and other features. Electron/Meteor.js-based, actively developed [on GitHub](https://github.com/nosqlclient/nosqlclient).
- [adminMongo](https://adminmongo.markmoffat.com/) - web-based or Electron app. Supports server monitoring and document editing.

### Closed source

- [NoSQLBooster](https://nosqlbooster.com) – [full-featured](https://nosqlbooster.com/features) shell-centric cross-platform GUI tool for MongoDB v2.2-4. Free, Personal, and Commercial editions ([feature comparison matrix](https://nosqlbooster.com/compareEditions)).
- [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) – provides a graphical user interface that allows you to visualize your schema and perform ad-hoc `find` queries against the database – all with zero knowledge of MongoDB's query language. Developed by MongoDB, Inc. [No `update` queries](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/COMPASS-3599) or access to the shell.
- [Studio 3T, formerly MongoChef](https://studio3t.com/) – a multi-platform in-place data browser and editor desktop GUI for MongoDB (Core version is free for personal and non-commercial use). *Last commit: 2017-Jul-24*
- [Robo 3T](http://www.robomongo.org/) – acquired by Studio 3T. A shell-centric cross-platform open source MongoDB management tool. Shell-related features only, e.g. multiple shells and results, autocomplete. No export/ import or other features are mentioned. *Last commit: 2017-Jul-04*
- [HumongouS.io](http://www.humongous.io/) – web-based interface with CRUD features, a chart builder and some collaboration capabilities. 14-day trial.
- [Database Master](http://www.nucleonsoftware.com/) – a Windows based MongoDB Management Studio, supports also RDBMS. **(not free)**
- [SlamData](http://slamdata.com) - an open source web-based user-interface that allows you to upload and download data, run queries, build charts, explore data.

### Abandoned projects

- [RockMongo](https://github.com/iwind/rockmongo) – a MongoDB administration tool, written in PHP5. Allegedly the best in the PHP world. Similar to PHPMyAdmin. *Last version: 2015-Sept-19*
- [Fang of Mongo](https://github.com/knutwalker/Fang-of-Mongo) – a web-based UI built with Django and jQuery. *Last commit: 2012-Jan-26, in a forked project.*
- [Opricot](https://github.com/argon/Opricot-MongoConsole) – a browser-based MongoDB shell written in PHP. *Latest version: 2010-Sep-21*
- [Futon4Mongo](https://github.com/sbellity/futon4mongo) – a clone of the [CouchDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CouchDB) Futon web interface for MongoDB. *Last commit: 2010-Oct-09*
- [MongoVUE](http://www.mongovue.com/) – an elegant GUI desktop application for Windows. **[Free and non-free versions.](http://www.mongovue.com/purchase/)** *Latest version: 2014-Jan-20*
- [UMongo](http://edgytech.com/umongo/) – a full-featured open-source MongoDB server administration tool for Linux, Windows, Mac; written in Java. *Last commit 2014-June*
- [Mongo3](http://mongo3.com/) – a Ruby/Sinatra-based interface for cluster management. *Last commit: Apr 16, 2013*

Comment: Great reply, very constructive indeed. Also if I may recomment: http://www.litixsoft.de/mms/

Comment: which of them can provide schema reference modification? wstorm cannot edit references

Comment: **Regarding MongoVUE** - I'm going to drop this here so hopefully people see it. MongoLab just updated most plans to v3.0 of MongoDB.  MongoVUE uses `mongod v2.6` authentication and hence now a LOT of people will no longer be able to remotely connect to any `mongodb v3.0` instance.  If you use another remote provider, and they use `>= v3.0 of mongodb`, you will no longer be able to connect

Comment: One word of advice if you are using MongoDB 3.2 with Robomongo on Windows. The latest version (http://app.robomongo.org/download.html) 0.8.5 does not properly work with MongoDB 3.2 causing the Explorer View to be empty, although collections and objects are created correctly. Please have a look at it: http://blog.robomongo.org/robomongo-rc2-for-windows-mac-os-x-and-linux/ and download version 0.9.0 RC2.

Comment: Additionally: https://github.com/rsercano/mongoclient written in meteorJS, has most platforms distributions.

Comment: I am using mongobooster. I like it.

Comment: This post appears after 90 minutes of search and reading, was typing around Mongo Admin, PHPMyAdmin equivalent and all sort of combination words.

Comment: thanks for a full list but it could be better if the answer is splitted into multiple ones people to vote on individual item.

Answer (score 12):

MongoVUE download is now available @ http://blog.mongovue.com/downloads

Comment: Note: While useful ... MongoVUE does not allow for editing of collections/documents at this time. However, here a Q&A about it's upcoming features: http://learnmongo.com/posts/qa-ishann-kumar-creator-of-mongovue/

Comment: MongoVUE is frustrating - it looks great and has some nice features, but once you start to use it you realise its limitations. You can't edit records or even remove embeded documents in the visual tool.

Comment: **WARNING:** [MongoVUE *seems* to be abandoned](http://blog.robiii.nl/2014/10/mongovue-gridfs-bug.html#abandoned)

Comment: It's certainly not yet compatible with mongoDB 3.0

Answer (score 4):

MongoVUE looks promising.

[http://mongovue.wordpress.com/](http://www.mongovue.com/)

Comment: As Justin has mentioned, this isn't really a full admin tool yet though.

Comment: **WARNING:** [MongoVUE *seems* to be abandoned](http://blog.robiii.nl/2014/10/mongovue-gridfs-bug.html#abandoned)

Answer (score 3):

The real answer is ... No.

So far as I have found there is no reasonable or publicly available Windows MonogoDB client which is really very sad since MongoDB is pretty sweet.

I've thought about throwing together a simple app with WPF on Codeplex ... but I haven't been super motivated.

What would features would you be interested in having? Maybe you can inspire me or others?

For example, do you just want to view DBs / collections & perhaps simple edits (so you don't have to use the shell) or do you require something more complex?

Comment: While useful I wouldn't ... say MongoVUE is yet a "true" visual tool. It does not allow for editing of collections/documents at this time (for example.) However, here a Q&A about it's upcoming features: http://learnmongo.com/posts/qa-ishann-kumar-creator-of-mongovue/

Comment: I agree, 'no' is currently the best answer.  Working with MongoDB on windows is more of a pain than it should be - simply because of the lack of tools.  Most of them listed on the MongoDB site are half-finished toy projects.

Comment: MongoVue is a great and most useful client , don't see why not using it

Comment: RoboMongo is a lot better than MongoVue (plus it's open source)

Answer (score 2):

MongoVue is the best I found till now, it has great features like database or collection copy and text mode viewing for records which is extremely useful

Comment: Update - Moved to RoboMongo

Comment: RoboMongo moved to Robo 3T

Answer (score 0):

I use MongoVUE, it's good for viewing data, but there is almost no editing abilities.

Answer (score -1):

There is a web-based project for this that is relatively early on called [Pongo](http://bitbucket.org/vrde/pongo/wiki/Home). It requires installing Python and some dependencies, but it should run on Windows.

Comment: Seems like slightly more headache than I'm willing to go through right now to get it up and running, but that looks like a great suggestion for anybody who already has the dependencies.

Comment: Pongo is dead. [No commits since 2010-Nov](https://bitbucket.org/vrde/pongo/commits/all).

Answer (score -2):

If you're able to run PHP scripts you can give [PHP MongoDB Admin](http://github.com/steves/php-mongodb-admin) a try. It's a single PHP script that gives you basic management and searching functionality.

Comment: This tool is dead. [No commits since 2010-Aug.](https://github.com/steves/php-mongodb-admin/commits/master). If you want a tool written in PHP, use [Rockmongo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6691013/1269037) instead.