# Mongo interface

Tags: mongodb

What are some GUIs to use with Mongo, and what features do they offer? I'm looking for facts here, not opinions on which interface is best.

Comment: Were one of the answers below helpful? If not can you provide some more detail?

Comment: What about Robomongo http://robomongo.org/?

Comment: Use either RoboMongo or RockMongo. These are pretty cool and free

Comment: Clever phrasing about opininons ;) But the picky admins closed it anyway ;)

Comment: found this very useful, +1 to asker and answerers, -1 to admins

Comment: For ubuntu (and possibly other distributions), see http://askubuntu.com/q/196136/79344

Comment: The mongo plugin fort intellij is pretty solid.

Comment: We looked or tried nearly every one available for Mac platforms, and 3t.io/mongochef/ is by far the best. Costs $39 USD, though, unless you're using the software for non-commercial purposes.

Comment: There are multiple GUI tools available from third parties: Mongovue, Mongohub, Robomongo, and JSON Studio.  Each has its strengths, and some work on specific OSes (Mac, Windows, Linux)

Comment: NoSqlManager, is very functional

Comment: Hello, as I investigated whole market, I didn't like any of them. Then decided to write my own. Here you are: https://github.com/rsercano/mongoclient written in meteorJS

Answer (score 92, accepted):

**Official List from MongoDB**

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs

**Web Based**

For PHP, I'd recommend Rock Mongo. Solid, lots of great features, easy setup.

http://rockmongo.com/

If you don't want to install anything ... you can use MongoHQ's web interface (even if you your MongoDB isn't on MongoHQ.)

https://mongohq.com/home

**Mac OS X**

While [MongoHub](http://mongohub.todayclose.com/) *had been* a decent option for a while it's bugs make it virtually unusable at this point ...

There is a more up-to-date (and less buggy) fork of the MongoHub project available: https://github.com/fotonauts/MongoHub-Mac you can download a binary [here](https://mongohub.s3.amazonaws.com/MongoHub.zip).

[image]

**Windows**

By far, the best UI (for Windows) currently out there  is MongoVUE.

http://blog.mongovue.com/

---

**WARNING/UPDATE:** [MongoVUE *seems* to be abandoned](http://blog.robiii.nl/2014/10/mongovue-gridfs-bug.html#abandoned).

---

Looks great, lots of features, and if you are new it will really help you get going ...

http://blog.mongovue.com/features/

Here's a Q&A with the author too if you are interested ...

http://learnmongo.com/posts/qa-ishann-kumar-creator-of-mongovue/

[image]

Comment: I agree, I really like Rock Mongo. It works flawlessly, has everything it needs to have, and takes about 30 seconds to install.

Comment: I highly recommend Rock Mongo as well. MongoVUE is not free and not as detailed as Rock Mongo

Comment: how do I use MongoHQ's web interface with my own databases?

Comment: +1 for rockmongo. Good stuff.

Comment: Just wanted to post an update that MongoHQ's web client no longer allows connections to databases that aren't hosted by MongoHQ.

Comment: I'd recommend robomongo. It's definitely my favorite thus far

Comment: Rock Mongo did not work flawlessly at all. My database was not localhost. It did not let me choose anything other than localhost on the web page login. The main readme told me nothing useful. So I  googled and searched numerous readme files, install.txt files and config files (copies of nginx and php are bundled in). I searched for all files containing "servers" and found config.php buried in a subdir. I copied their lines and added my own server name and it still doesn't work. No user/pass is needed but rockmongo errors "authenticate failed". This seems like a hacked together tool.

Comment: Update: To add a server, edit web\rockmongo\config.php. Copy from line mongo_name..Localhost to "$i ++;". Replace desired values esp mongo_host, mongo_port, mongo_db, mongo_name. For no auth, make control_auth false (mongo_auth should already be false).

Comment: http://mongotron.io/ is a GUI that is built on a web stack

Comment: Give it a shot: https://github.com/rsercano/mongoclient

Answer (score 19):

On Mac there is [MongoHub](http://mongohub.todayclose.com/). On Windows you could try [MongoVUE](http://blog.mongovue.com/).

Also see [Do any visual tools exist for MongoDB (for Windows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310242/do-any-visual-tools-exist-for-mongodb-for-windows)

Screenshot of MongoHub:
[image: MongoHub fotonauts fork build of 2012-03-15]

Comment: Beware, MongoHub is buggy. I was inserting data with it and it wasn't showing up. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825015/mongodb-why-are-find-and-findone-only-returning-last-array-element/

Comment: Have you tried the really more developed fork [fotonauts](https://github.com/fotonauts/MongoHub-Mac)? Seems way more mature to me.

Comment: `MongoHub` should be renamed `MongoBug`, it's super buggy ... I can't recommend it. Crashes *all the time**.

Comment: https://github.com/rsercano/mongoclient is compatible with most of the platforms

Answer (score 8):

Here's the [official page of Admin UIs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs).

I have not really used any of them. But it looks like there is quite a bit of coverage there.

Answer (score 5):

**Web**

At the shop where I work we use the Prudence platform for some stuff, and also MongoDB, so we of course use MongoVision a lot. Browser based, tabbed collection views, pretty-printed document editor, and three themes OOB. Open source.

[image: MongoVision]
<sub>(source: [threecrickets.com](http://threecrickets.com/media/mongovision-screenshot.png))</sub>

http://code.google.com/p/mongo-vision/

**OS X**

Being on a Mac, I wish [MongoHub](https://web.archive.org/web/20150512231144/http://mongohub.todayclose.com:80/) was as reliable as MongoVision. <strike>It probably will be soon though, since [the project has been quite active on Github](https://github.com/bububa/MongoHub-Mac) as of late.</strike>

[image: MongoHub]
<sub>(source: [skitch.com](https://img.skitch.com/20120111-d2rtgxxc7193w89su1jjwremtp.png))</sub>

http://mongohub.todayclose.com/

Comment: MongoHub is not quite active right now.

Comment: @Musaffa you are correct, but it was at the time I wrote that (two and a half years ago). I'll cross that remark out.

Answer (score 1):

try [Mongo Explorer](http://mongoexplorer.com). you'll like it!

Answer (score 1):

try [mongoVue](http://www.mongovue.com/) i'm using it and i think it's good enough