# Query IDE for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I'm wondering if there is an IDE for MongoDB that allows you to run queries and see the results? This would behave like query analyzer in SQL Server Management Studio. The issue I'm having right now is that I have to do queries, such as "db.MyTable.find()" from command prompt, which isn't a good solution.

If the answer is no, is there a more mature "no sql" solution like MongoDB that does have an IDE?

Comment: I have been using MongoHub (http://mongohub.todayclose.com/) on my mac, which platform are you talking about?

Comment: Check out http://www.MongoChef.com/.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Web Based**

For PHP, I'd recommend Rock Mongo. Solid, lots of great features, easy setup.

http://code.google.com/p/rock-php/wiki/rock_mongo

If you don't want to install anything ... you can use MongoHQ's web interface (even if you your MongoDB isn't on MongoHQ.)

https://mongohq.com/home

**Windows**

By far, the best UI (for Windows) currently out there  is MongoVUE.

http://blog.mongovue.com/

Looks great, lots of features, and if you are new it will really help you get going ...

http://blog.mongovue.com/features/

Here's a Q&A with the author too if you are interested ...

http://learnmongo.com/posts/qa-ishann-kumar-creator-of-mongovue/

There is an official list of admin tools here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs

[image]

Comment: See this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/q/4269688/296167

Comment: Thanks! I saw an IDE for mac and got discouraged when that was all I found, I'm happy that Windows is getting some love too.

Comment: yeah check out mongovue, constantly being updated too ...

Comment: Mongovue looks ok, one thing though is it seems that you can't write a query and execute it to see the results. You have to use their find option, which forces you to put in parts of the query into different textboxes, pretty annoying unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I believe that's in the plans to add in future versions but I'm not sure ...

Comment: It's a sorry state of affairs when the best we have is MongoVue :( It's ok for viewing DB content, but as an admin tool it is extremely limited.

Comment: Also, MongoVue does not support aggregation. It has not been updated since April.

Comment: What's more, if you take a look at their Facebook page, apparently they still accept orders and never send license keys -- you're throwing money into a bit bucket.

Comment: One obvious caveat when using MongoHQ. Your mongo server has to be publicly available. This is usually not the case when you are developing a proper application and your server is only available to your application.

Comment: As of June 2015 - RockMongo site has been down for several months, and [no activity on Github either](https://github.com/iwind/rockmongo/issues/96).

Comment: mongohq became compose.com

Answer (score 78):

Another contender : http://www.robomongo.org/
Robo 3T (formerly Robomongo) give you a shell like interface but outputs your results in the gui.
Its available for windows, mac(dmg, zip) and linux (deb, rpm, tar.gz) as a desktop application. Currently there is a free community version (no ads, all features) and payed ones with more support and influence on backlog.

Robo 3T (formerly Robomongo) prints the results in a treeView or Json text representation and supports the generation of UUID (.NET-,Python-,Java-Encoding). It has autocomplete, shows multiple results at once and has a query history.

[image: Robomongo screenshots (linux, mac, windows)]

Comment: Coming soon for linux. Keeping my fingers crossed and waiting.

Comment: One vote for the console

Comment: looks promising but build for Linux is not ready and too complecated

Comment: @RomanIvanov: Precompiled Linux binaries have been available for download since the end of April (2013): http://www.robomongo.org/

Comment: Robomongo now have rpm and dep packages for linux platforms, dmg for Mac Os(10.6-10.9), and nsis for Windows(Xp-8)

Comment: +1 I have been using since last 4 motnhs, Its a awesome and better then any other

Comment: I've tried Robomongo but I have no idea how to edit a document. Right click isn't working, neither double clicking on a field to edit it. And I don't see any query history.

Answer (score 1):

Still using MongoVue, (licensed version) but I find it too limited. An admin UI should provide you basic functionality like delete record by right click, set to null, insert data with picker, etc. Finally ended up writing updating json queries from the console.

While checking out mongodb admin tools page after my frustration with MongoVue, came across with the following. Don't quite like these all-in-one tools but I think I'll give it a try

http://www.nucleonsoftware.com/Products/Database-Master

Comment: Right click to delete is available in Robomongo. Updating and Inserting is also very easy. As a bonus your actions taken utilize the regular mongodb console syntax so its easy to reuse or script what has been done in the ui.

Comment: will try this too, although it looks like more of a power shell, GUI looks clean and i definitely love frequent updates!

Comment: @ThomasS do you know if there's a table view? (at least to some extent like mongovue) right click delete feels good :)

Comment: A table view as pictured here http://www.mongovue.com/2010/12/06/viewing-hierarchical-data-in-table-view/ is not available in robomongo at the current time. A textview and treeview is available though.