# Database administration tool for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-administration

I'm kinda confused. MongoDB is one of the most popular DB. Is there any DB administration tool available for MongoDB like MySQL workbench or [localhost web based] PHPMyadmin.

I'm on windows 7 machine.

Comment: There are several web and native apps. You should have googled before asking this question.

Comment: Why is this question not constructive? Come on guys, what gives? Please reopen this.

Comment: Please check RoboMongo .https://robomongo.org/.........

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The mongo documentation has some suggestions: 
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs

Fang looks interesting

Comment: I c RokMango will be best suited to me. Oh i c this question is duplicate but to be honest I don't c those listed on suggestion. @mcalex, thanks for ur answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741407/query-ide-for-mongodb/4741612#4741612