# A GUI tool for MongoDB

Tags: user-interface, mongodb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mongo interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269688/mongo-interface)

I have been going through the GUI tools available for mongoDB. I got to see the mongoHub (sad that it works only on MAC OSX) ,rockMongo and some other php based tools. Is there any other tool available which is a desktop application something like the MYSQL GUI tools?

Comment: Given this page comes top in Google rankings, it's a bit of a shame that it's been closed and marked as duplicate. The Admin UI page of Mongo is horribly out of date and references the original MongoHub Mac client, which is no longer maintained. This fork seems to be the most active and stable: https://github.com/fotonauts/MongoHub-Mac

Comment: Check [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/) out

Comment: Try Robomongo http://robomongo.org/, shell-centric cross-platform solution.

Comment: http://mongodb-tools.com/

Comment: Stackoverflow you can do better.

Comment: @MikeBartlett, plus the other question was closed, so it's even worse.

Comment: I totally agree with Mike Bartlett. Anyway I'd recommend [MongoChef by 3T](http://3t.io/mongochef/), it's cross-platform, GUI support for loads of common tasks and awesome shell intellisense. [MongoChef was favourably compared to others on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/mongodb/comments/2w7j0f/better_tools_for_mongodb_redgate_invests_in_3t/) too.

Comment: I just released a minimalist mongodb data viewer for nodejs [github.com/marcdelalonde/mongo-viewer](https://github.com/marcdelalonde/mongo-viewer)

Comment: Here you are: https://github.com/rsercano/mongoclient written in meteorJS, has most platforms distributions.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[Admin UI](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs) page of Mongodb provides some useful links. Check out

Comment: out of date.. need a more up to date tool

Comment: check robomongo.org

Comment: checkout https://github.com/digitalmaster/mongocms/

Comment: I'm developing one myself: https://github.com/Hrish2006/MongoMan.

Comment: MAC OS X use mongohub free tool  http://mongohub.todayclose.com/

Comment: My tool of choice is [3T MongoChef](http://3t.io/mongochef/download/platform/). It's available for Mac, Windows and Linux.

Comment: I just released a minimalist mongodb data viewer for nodejs [github.com/marcdelalonde/mongo-viewer](https://github.com/marcdelalonde/mongo-viewer)

Comment: Additionally: https://github.com/rsercano/mongoclient written in meteorJS, has most platforms distributions.