# Is there any free / Open source Mongo DB browser available?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongoose, mongodb-.net-driver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mongo interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269688/mongo-interface)

I am new to mongo db, and i am looking for a user interface for Mongo DB,  I am storing data in my Mongo Db and want to check If its getting Stored there. Is there any browser available by which i can check the database values. Thanks In Advance

Comment: Here you are: https://github.com/rsercano/mongoclient written in meteorJS, has most platforms distributions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/978460363/even-more-mongodb-tools

http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/334469038/a-couple-of-nice-gui-tools-for-mongodb

http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/452431400/myngo-like-phpmyadmin-for-mongodb

http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/831818823/rockmongo-yet-another-mongodb-management-and-admin

http://mongohub.todayclose.com/

Comment: Additionally :  https://github.com/rsercano/mongoclient written in meteorJS, has most platforms distributions.

Answer (score 1):

I use RockMongo. Good tool, clean user interface.