# MongoDB: why are find and findOne only returning last array element?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Why when I do a findOne (same with find), does it only show me the last item in my "acts" array. My collection only contains one document for test purposes.

I'm doing this in the mongo cli: db.mycollection.findOne();

My result of findOne():

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f0db64659d044892271018f"),
    "title" : "Awards Show 2012",
    "description" : "An amazing awards show",
    "acts" : [
        {
            "name" : "Act 3",
            "description" : "My act description"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my document:

```
 {
  "_id": { "$oid" : "4F0DB64659D044892271018F" },
  "title": "Awards Show 2012",
  "description": "An amazing awards show",
  "acts": [
    {
      "name": "Act 1",
      "description": "My act description"
    },
    {
      "name": "Act 2",
      "description": "My act description"
    },
    {
      "name": "Act 3",
      "description": "My act description"
    }
  ]
}
```

**EDIT: Fixed the document - had a typo**

Comment: if `findOne` returns a document with only one item, and `find` does the same, how do you know 'your document' is in the database at all?

Comment: Because I am also using MongoHub (gui for mac). And I can browse my collection and expand my document. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/uEojd.png

Comment: I think I might have found the problem. I don't think the document was being inserted by MongoHub properly. Troubleshooting, I'll be back with more detail shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoHub is really buggy. Please don't use it. RockMongo and Genghis are quite good.

Comment: Yep, it was MongoHub that was screwing up. I was inserting via MongoHub and it said it was inserting all of the array elements, and even returning that on a find, but Mongo client proved different. I'll check out RockMongo and Genghis.

Comment: Just checked them out. I would prefer a GUI for Mac so I don't have to rely on rails or PHP.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a really good GUI for Mac yet. There's a good one that's Windows specific called MongoVUE, but that won't help you.

For the most part the web ones are further along for cross platform use.

Comment: Genghis 2.0 has been released and no longer depends on PHP or apache. There is a ruby gem for it and it's completely self contained. Works well cross platform.