# Searching for a MongoDB user interface

Tags: mongodb, user-interface

I searching for mongodb gui user interface & database desinger tool. Does anyone of you knows a tool which he could recommend?

Comment: Google: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/

Comment: I already know rockMongo.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3310242/1259510

Answer (score 2):

I will strongly recommend [RoboMongo](http://robomongo.org/) - shell-centric cross-platform open source MongoDB management tool

Answer (score 1):

RoboMongo http://robomongo.org/ is awesome, it needs virtually zero configuration,very easy to use , gives you the power of mongo shell in GUI ,has auto completion feature and works on all platforms, yet another advantage is it is still under active maintenance. I have tried tools like RockMongo and ran into usability issues. MongoUVE is not opensource, it is commercial.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [MongoVUE](http://www.mongovue.com/) for a while. The free version can do everything I wanted sofar.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows7 I'm using [MongoExplorer](http://mongoexplorer.com/), a very easy and visual tool